# join two/three table from one model in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0

I have models writed as in picture (http://hosting5578581.az.pl/img/association.png), i can figure out how can i fetch data (in ORDER model) as in picture, i can fetch from OrderItems items wich are related with some order but i dont know how to display it as NAME (which is in Items table) in mysql query i can do this by (for example order_id=1):

> `select items.name from order_items, items WHERE order_items.item_id =
>   items.item_id AND order_items.order_id = 1;`

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

It's very well documented (click link above) and allows you to pull whatever associated data you want.

Note:  You should almost exclusively be using [CakePHP's find()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find) instead of your own custom MySQL queries.

It will eventually look something like this:

```
$this->Order->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $orderId
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Customer',
        'OrderItem' => array(
            'Item'
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question, you need some way:

```
$this->recursive = 2;   
$this->read(null, $id);
```

Where id is number of order

Comment: Setting recursive to anything other than -1 is bad advice IMO.

Answer (score 0):

@Dave:
In my OrdersController i have code:

```
$products = $this->Order->find('first', array(

            'contain' => array (
                'Customer',
                'OrderItem' => array(
                    'Item'
                )
            )
                 ));
```

after find() query i get this result 
(i omit array 'Order' and 'Customer' - are no important now):

```
array(

'OrderItem' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'order_id' => '1',
            'item_id' => '4',
            'quantity' => '2',
            'Item' => array()
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'order_id' => '1',
            'item_id' => '6',
            'quantity' => '1',
            'Item' => array()
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'order_id' => '1',
            'item_id' => '7',
            'quantity' => '1',
            'Item' => array()
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'order_id' => '1',
            'item_id' => '8',
            'quantity' => '1',
            'Item' => array()
        )
    )
)
```

1.So how can I get all 'products' now ? i started with something similar to this but i know that it is bad because i must write ['0']...['1]... which is dynamic variable

```
<?php echo h($products['OrderItem']['0']['item_id']); ?>
```

2.As you can see

> 'Item' => array()

is null ;-) so i cant get for example the name of the item from a Item table/model